# How do I represent recursion in my filtration set?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

- Let's take a super simple stochastic process consisting of one coin toss.
- Normally I would have $\mathcal{F}=\{\{\},\{T\},\{H\},\{T,H\}\}$
- Now let's say that if I get heads, I toss again.
- How would my new $\mathcal{F}'$ set look like?

---

**Update**: the process is meant to continue indefinitely if I keep getting $H$, so imagine the filtration symbol $\mathcal{F}'$ would have to be re-used in the set itself

Answer (score 1):

The smallest $\sigma -$algebra that describe your experiment is $$\mathcal F'=\sigma \{\{(H,H)\},\{(H,T)\}\},$$
but the problem with this $\sigma -$agebra it's that it's not complete. The best would be to take $$\mathcal F'=\mathcal F\otimes \mathcal F=2^{\Omega\times \Omega }.$$

Answer (score 1):

You could start with sample space $\Omega=\{HH,HT,TH,TT\}$ and the associated power set (with 16 elements) as $\sigma$-field. But as you won't perform a second toss if the first toss is a head, you don't care to distinguish between $TT$ and $TH$. So an adequate $\sigma$ field would be
$$
\left\{\emptyset,\Omega,\{HH\},\{HT\},\{TH,TT\},\{HH,HT\},\{TH,TT,HT\},\{TH,TT,HH\}\right\},
$$
in which any event containing one of $TH$ or $TT$ also contains the other.

Alternatively, you could take your sample space to be $\{HT, HH,T\}$, acknowledging that you stop with one toss if it's a $T$. With this choice the power set would be the appropriate $\sigma$-field.